# How to add subresources integrity with Angular appShell build

Tags: build, server-side-rendering, app-shell, angular-cli-v9

I built an application with Angular CLI 9.
I patched the `package.json` file with :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --subresource-integrity",
    "prebuild:prod": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' ts-node ./sitemap_generator.ts"
  }
}
```

So, when I called `npm run build:prod`, my 2 commands are executed and output files generated by compiler contains SRI.

Now, I added the appShell :

`npm run ng generate appShell -- --client-project my-project`

To run the build *with* the appShell, I have to use the command :

`npm run ng run my-project:app-shell:production`

**MAIN QUESTION**

But this command calls `my-project:build:production` configuration of `angular.json` file, and this does not accept the `--subresource-integrity` argument :/

How to patch this to have appShell production build *with* SRI ?

**SECONDARY QUESTION *for the braves***

This appShell build create a `server/` folder in `dist/`. It just contains a `main.js` file. I suppose it's internally used with Node to build the appShell ; can someone confirm that ?
And so, can I use Unversal too with this architecture to do some SSR for search engines ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a way by editing angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "my-project",
  "projects": {
    "oce-training": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "subresourceIntegrity": true,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, we cannot override on `package.json` or by CLI command, but it's sufficient for my case.

Now I have in `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:prod": "ng run oce-training:app-shell:production",
    "prebuild:prod": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' ts-node ./sitemap_generator.ts"
  },
}
```

My question about SSR is maintained, but it could be another Stackoverflow post ;)